# Enumerable.Empty<T>() equivalent for IQueryable

Tags: c#, return, iqueryable

When a method returns `IEnumerable<T>` and I do not have anything to return, we can use `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`.

Is there an equivalent to the above for a method returning `IQueryable<T>`

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Maybe:

```
Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
```

Comment: I know, currently that is the only simple, direct & dirty ;-) solution

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't create an actual empty IQueryable, which means it causes e.g. `Union` queries to be broken up into multiple queries instead of one.

Comment: @NetMage That's right. What is more confusing is that your code don't break in the line where is `Union`, but probably when you try something after this. This answer is accepted and voted but it can be very misleading. @Sunny Please consider to edit your answer. Answer in this question helped me: [Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable(); This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815309/enumerable-emptyt-asqueryable-this-method-supports-the-linq-to-entities-i) .

Answer (score 35):

`Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();` should do it.

Answer (score 7):

Try `return new T[0].AsQueryable();`

Comment: @Nauman - you actually create an [empty] T array - no new object of T is actually created.

Answer (score 7):

Say you have an `IQueryable<T>` called `result`:

```
return result.Take(0);
```

Answer (score 5):

I would advise against alejandrobog's answer as this will still use memory to create an empty array.

```
Array.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
```

or

```
Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
```

are preferred. Array.Empty will allocate a static typed array so only one empty array of T is created and that is shared amongst all Empty queryables.

Comment: `Array.Empty<T>` is only available after .NET Framework 4.6. For earlier versions, you can use `new object[0].Cast<T>()`

Answer (score 1):

Enumerable.Empty().AsQueryable(); is wrong since Union will break and wont work. Workaround is

```
var db = new DbContext();
var query = db.Set<T>().Take(0);
```

Comment: Take(0) is the right approach. The Empty() way also breaks Concat, and probably any other method that tries to build on the empty queryable.