# How to convert UNION ALL to OR in Linq to SQL expression trees (Oracle ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected got CLOB)

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I am working with `EF6` and am using db first generated models for `MSSQL` and `Oracle`. In few places I am searching by multiple search criteria which results in `UNION ALL` sql generated where each query is being in it's own sub-select.

One of columns in `Oracle` table is `CLOB` and `linq to sql` after it wraps all selects with `UNION ALL` at the top of all `UNIONS` it calls `SELECT DISTINCT 
  "UnionAll1"."UNIQUE_ID" AS "C1", ...` [which requires to compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732302/error-ora-00932-when-using-a-select-with-union-and-clob-fields) `CLOB`s and fails on Oracle side.

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException:
>   ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

**Is there a way to remove that `DISTINCT` statement? How can I make this work?**

**UPDATE**
Mechanism that generates LINQ looks like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySearch<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, SearchModel search) where T : class 
{
    var subQueries = new List<IQueryable<T>>();
    if (search != null)
    {
        if (search.PolicyNumber.HasValue && typeof (IPolicyNumber).IsAssignableFrom(queryable.ElementType))
        {
            subQueries.Add(queryable.SearchByPolicyNumber(search));
        }

        if (search.UniqueId.HasValue && typeof (IUniqueId).IsAssignableFrom(queryable.ElementType))
        {
            subQueries.Add(queryable.SearchByUniqueId(search));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.PostCode) && typeof(IPostCode).IsAssignableFrom(queryable.ElementType))
        {
            subQueries.Add(queryable.SearchByPostCode(search));
        }
    }

    return subQueries.DefaultIfEmpty(queryable)
        .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Union(b));
}
```

Example of specific search method:

```
 public static IQueryable<IRequestId> SearchByRequestId<IRequestId>(this IQueryable<IRequestId> queryable, SearchModel search)
    {
        var interfacesToColumnNames = new Dictionary<Type, string>
        {
            {typeof (IRequestId<>), "requestid"},
            {typeof (IRequest_Id<>), "request_id"},
        };

        var paramLambda = Expression.Parameter(typeof (IRequestId));
        var columnLambda = Expression.Property(paramLambda, interfacesToColumnNames.Single(o => queryable.ElementType.GetInterfaces().Any(oo => oo.Name == o.Key.Name)).Value);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IRequestId, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(columnLambda, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(search.RequestId), columnLambda.Type)), paramLambda);
        queryable = queryable.Where(lambda);

        return queryable;
    }
```

Example where it gets called in controller:

```
 public ActionResult QUOTE_HOUSE()
    {
        var onlineDocs =
            this.DatabaseManager.GetEntities<QUOTE_HOUSE>().ApplySearch(Search)
                .Take(10);
        return View("QUOTE_HOUSE", onlineDocs.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: @berkser Hi, which code would you like to see?

Comment: It would be good if you include at least one problematic LINQ query. If I understand correctly, you are not doing explicitly `Distinct` or `Union`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Hi Ivan, most certainly not, reason I refrained of adding code it is quite complicated and might distract many with length and complexity from what I am actually trying to achieve. You can have a look at the code that combines results in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815309/enumerable-emptyt-asqueryable-this-method-supports-the-linq-to-entities-i#answer-37815457

Comment: Hi Matas, I remember that question :) So the union is actually generated by you.

Comment: Any option to replace that union with `or` predicates? i.e. instead of `queryable.SearchByXXX(search)` which returns queryable with `Where` applied (I guess) to get only the where expressions, and then combine them with `Or` inside a single `Where`?

Comment: @IvanStoev I like this idea with `OR` chances are will be faster too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the additional information from the comments, the problematic queries are produced by the following procedure:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySearch<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, SearchModel search) where T : class 
{
    var subQueries = new List<IQueryable<T>>();
    if (search != null)
    {
        if (search.PolicyNumber.HasValue && typeof (IPolicyNumber).IsAssignableFrom(queryable.ElementType))
        {
            subQueries.Add(queryable.SearchByPolicyNumber(search));
        }

        if (search.UniqueId.HasValue && typeof (IUniqueId).IsAssignableFrom(queryable.ElementType))
        {
            subQueries.Add(queryable.SearchByUniqueId(search));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.PostCode) && typeof(IPostCode).IsAssignableFrom(queryable.ElementType))
        {
            subQueries.Add(queryable.SearchByPostCode(search));
        }
    }

    return subQueries.DefaultIfEmpty(queryable)
        .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Union(b));
}
```

where I assume the supporting methods are something like this

```
public static IQueryable<T> SearchByPolicyNumber<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, SearchModel search) where T : class 
{
    return queryable.Where(x => predicate_using_PolicyNumber(x, search));
}

public static IQueryable<T> SearchByUniqueId<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, SearchModel search) where T : class 
{
    return queryable.Where(x => predicate_using_UniqueId(x, search));
}

public static IQueryable<T> SearchByPostCode<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, SearchModel search) where T : class 
{
    return queryable.Where(x => predicate_using_PostCode(x, search));
}
```

The problem is that EF translates the LINQ `Union` operator to SQL `UNION ALL` subquery with applied `DISTINCT SELECT ...` as you already found. I have no idea why it does it this way instead of simply translating it to SQL `UNION`, but actually there is no guarantee that it would work with such type of columns either.

The only way to solve the issue I see is to eliminate the `Union` operator by replacing it with a single `Where` with `Or` conditions. In order to do that, you have to slightly change your design.

First, extract the predicate part from the supporting methods:

```
public static class SearchPredicates
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ByPolicyNumber<T>(SearchModel search) where T : class 
    {
        return x => predicate_using_PolicyNumber(x, search);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ByUniqueId<T>(SearchModel search) where T : class 
    {
        return x => predicate_using_UniqueId(x, search);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ByPostCode<T>(SearchModel search) where T : class 
    {
        return x => predicate_using_PostCode(x, search);
    }
}
```

Then modify the main method like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySearch<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, SearchModel search) where T : class 
{
    var predicates = new List<Expression<<Func<T, bool>>>();
    if (search != null)
    {
        if (search.PolicyNumber.HasValue && typeof (IPolicyNumber).IsAssignableFrom(queryable.ElementType))
            predicates.Add(SearchPredicates.ByPolicyNumber(search));
        if (search.UniqueId.HasValue && typeof (IUniqueId).IsAssignableFrom(queryable.ElementType))
            predicates.Add(SearchPredicates.ByUniqueId(search));
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.PostCode) && typeof(IPostCode).IsAssignableFrom(queryable.ElementType))
            predicates.Add(SearchPredicates.ByPostCode(search));
    }
    if (predicates.Count == 0)
        return queryable;

    var parameter = predicates[0].Parameters[0];
    var condition = predicates[0].Body;
    for (int i = 1; i < predicates.Count; i++)
        condition = Expression.Or(condition, predicates[i].Body.ReplaceParameter(predicates[i].Parameters[0], parameter));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(condition, parameter);
    return queryable.Where(predicate);
}
```

You can use any EF compatible predicate builder, here I'm building the predicate manually. The helper method used is:

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

With all that applied, hopefully the issue will be resolved.

Comment: Ivan you are a star it does seem to work :), WHERE clause now looks like this. `AND ((1001 = "Extent1"."POLICY_NO") OR (900000977 = "Extent1"."UNIQUE_ID"))`.

Comment: Cool :) And looking at the updated post, the transition to predicate seems to be even easier than I thought.

Comment: yep only had to return `lambdas` :) I have also changed this bit `f (predicates.Count == 0)
                return queryable;

            var oredWhere = predicates.Aggregate((a, b) =>
            {
                var param = a.Parameters[0];
                var cond = a.Body;
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Or(cond, b.Body.ReplaceParameter(b.Parameters[0], param)),param);
            });

            return queryable.Where(oredWhere);` I just had to use `Aggregate` somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured an alternative.

`return subQueries.DefaultIfEmpty(queryable)
        .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Concat(b));`

then after `ToList()` where you are actually using output `.Distinct(new YourEqualityComparer()))`. To filter out possible duplicates.

This isn't ideal solution since requires you to manually implement `IEquitable` on structures, but if you are after performance it is likely to be faster. `OR` will require composite indexes on database while querying by two separate single column indexes then combining the data will be not require to have all possible column-index combinations on table. Another downside you are likely to use `Take()` before `ToList()` and then after filtering you might get to few records (and have to re-query).