# How to instantiate IQueryable() in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

You are writing unit tests and you want to insatiate an IQueryable() interface.
How exactly?

Comment: Duplicate of [Instantiate empty IQueryable for use with Linq to sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993048/instantiate-empty-iqueryable-for-use-with-linq-to-sql), [Enumerable.Empty<T>() equivalent for IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2691392/8967612)

Answer (score 1):

One straight forward way would be creating object implementing interface, or to use `AsQueryable()` method on `IEnumerable`, as suggested in other answer.

One more way, as generally is done with interfaces, is to use mocks, like

```
var queryableMock = new Mock<IQueryable>();
// Setup mock with queryableMock.Setup method,
// now you can use queryableMock.Object
```

Answer (score 0):

To instantiate an empty object use the following code where T is your entity type

```
using System.Linq;

var query = Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
```

To instantiate an object with a list of entries:

```
var query = (new List<T> { new T()}).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: I think better to use `default(T)`